# No puedo crear un ejecutable porque utilice Cyhunspell en Python

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, hunspell

Utilice la librería Cyhunspell en lugar de hunspell por la facilidad de su instalación, pero después de terminar el programa no me deja crear un ejecutable que funcione, me aparece el siguiente error: No module named 'hunspell.platform' [image: No module named 'hunspell.platform']

Saben como puedo crear un ejecutable que funcione, o que opciones tengo.
Les agradezco

Answer (score 0):

La solución que encontré es cambiar de librería. Utilicé enchant, que utiliza los mismos diccionarios que hunspell (cyhunspell), y tiene funciones que realizan lo mismo que había hecho con cyhunspell.

Para instalarla se utiliza:

```
pip install pyenchant
```